# get data from mLab using modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, find, mlab

I trying to get data from mLab.
In function /getAll I am trying to get all the JSONs I entered in a collection.
I understood that to get all of the details I need to use the function find.
When I run it (node app.js) - I can see it waiting but nothing happens and I don't get anything on localhost:3000/getAll (it's not loading)

here is app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var stud = require('./grades');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://<myuser>:<mypass>@<dataaddress>');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

mongoose.connection.once('open', function(){
    stud(app);
    mongoose.disconnect();
});


app.listen(port);
```

and this is gadres.js

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var util = require('util');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema;

var studSchema = new schema({
    id  : {type:Number, unique:true, required:true},
    name : {type:String, required:true},
    grade : Number,
    course : {type:String},
    year : Number
},{collection: 'details'});

var stud = mongoose.model('stud', studSchema);

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/getAll', function(req, res) { // if url in path is getAll
     stud.find({}, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
     });
    })
});
```

Comment: Do you have anything in console atlocalhost:3000/getAll ? Or do you get 404 error on that address ? Or anything else ?

Comment: no.. I don't get anything it's just have a loading sign

Comment: Did you try to work with more files so you don't get lost in the code, for example using grades.js where you put the Schema and mongoose stuff, then a gradesRoute.js where you add the '/getAll' route, and then a controller and a service if needed ? Or do you need to work with just one file doing all these at once ?
Consider splitting in different files, so it will be easier to find where your problem is.